# Autolink words in a string if they exist in array

Tags: php, string, replace

I have an array of words and links like this one (sorted by length):

```
$replacement = array = [
    'another example' => 'http://another-example.com',
    'examples' => 'http://examples.com',
    'example' => 'http://example.com',
];
```

And I have a text like this one:

```
$content = "Two examples are the combination of an example and another example.";
```

I want to replace the words by links with the keywords generating a result like this:

```
Two <a href="http://examples.com">examples</a> are the combination of an <a href="http://example.com">example</a> and <a href="http://another-example.com">another example</a>.
```

So, my approach is to sort the keyword array by length and replace the key for the value and, some how, avoid the script to replace words within the link (anchor text and `href` attribute)... the problem is... how do I avoid the replacement within the link?

**Bonus:** it will be nice if the function only autolink the first appearance of the keyword and not generate a link every time the keyword appears.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 2):

You can try [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php).

> If given two arguments, the second should be an array in the form array('from' => 'to', ...). The return value is a string where all the occurrences of the array keys have been replaced by the corresponding values. **The longest keys will be tried first. Once a substring has been replaced, its new value will not be searched again**.

```
$content = strtr($content, $replacement);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but strtr looks to replace incomplete word. For example: it can makes replacements like `lottery` for `<a href="http://lot.com">lot</a>tery` if `lot` is in the list.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you want to change your replacement array a little bit, so that you can easily replace text with the correct link. Then, you can use `strtr()`.

```
foreach ($replacement as $orig => $sub) {
    $replacement[$orig] = '<a href="'.$sub.'">'.$orig.'</a>';
}

/* So now $replacement looks like this:
array(3) {
    ["another example"]=>
        string(56) "<a href="http://another-example.com">another example</a>"
    ["examples"]=>
        string(42) "<a href="http://examples.com">examples</a>"
    ["example"]=>
        string(40) "<a href="http://example.com">example</a>"
}
*/

$content = strtr($content, $replacement);
```

EDIT:

If you want exact word matches, you're going to need regular expressions. Here's how I would try to do it:

```
$content = "Two examples are the combination of an example and another example.";

$replacement = array(
    'another example' => 'http://another-example.com',
    'examples' => 'http://examples.com',
    'example' => 'http://example.com',
);
$new_replacement = array();

foreach ($replacement as $orig => $sub) {
    $new_replacement['/\b'.$orig.'\b/'] = '<a href="'.$sub.'">'.$orig.'</a>';
}

$orig = array_keys($new_replacement);
$sub = array_values($new_replacement);

$content = preg_replace($orig, $sub, $content, 1);

echo $content;
```

Comment: This almost works to me. The issue is that if "examples" doesn't exist in the array, it will replace "examples" for `<a href="http://example.com">example</a>s` Note the S out of the tag.

Comment: I actually thought that was correct. Do you mean that you only want to replace exact and complete words?

Comment: For example: it can makes replacements like `lottery` for `<a href="http://lot.com">lot</a>tery` if `lot` is in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You're need to use preg_replace with `\b`. That will limit the replacement to complete words.
I use implode to build the regex pattern to become like:

```
"\b(another example)|(examples)|(example)\b/"
```

Then the replacement uses what the regex captures.

```
$replacement = [
    'another example' => 'http://another-example.com',
    'examples' => 'http://examples.com',
    'example' => 'http://example.com',
];

$content = "Two examples are the combination of an example and another example.";

echo preg_replace("/\b(". implode(")|(", array_keys($replacement)) . ")\b/", "<a href=\"$0\">$0</a>", $content);
```

Output:

```
Two <a href="examples">examples</a> are the combination of an <a href="example">example</a> and <a href="another example">another example</a>.
```

https://3v4l.org/1Jhak

---

In order to get the bonus to work we need to use the fourth argument of preg_replace and loop the array.
This limits preg_replace to only make one replacement.

```
$replacement = [
    'another example' => 'http://another-example.com',
    'examples' => 'http://examples.com',
    'example' => 'http://example.com',
];

$content = "Two examples are the combination of an example and another example, 
Two examples are the combination of an example and another example.";


foreach($replacement as $find => $repl){
    $content =  preg_replace("/\b(". $find . ")\b/", "<a href=\"$repl\">$0</a>", $content, 1);
}
echo $content;
```

Output:

```
Two <a href="http://examples.com">examples</a> are the combination of an <a href="http://example.com">example</a> and <a href="http://another-example.com">another example</a>, 
Two examples are the combination of an example and another example.
```

https://3v4l.org/8GFZr

Comment: @Thefourthbird maybe.. I'm just about to edit to make the "bonus" work. I'll look in to this later.

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes. I see your point but since OP wants limit to 1 then that won't work anyways. I think, or at least I can't.

Comment: This almost works but it generates `<a href="examples">examples</a>` instead of `<a href="http://examples.com">examples</a>`. Note the href value is different.

Comment: @CoolGuy that is a typo from my side, easy fix. Edited the "bonus" way to include correct links. I assume that is the method you want.

Comment: This one fails if the longest word comes before the shortest. See: https://3v4l.org/kfFgq